# QT C++ The last QPushButton created is the only QPushButton that will process the mouse clicked event

Tags: c++, qt

I have coded up a C++ QT test application to place 4 QPushButtons (QuitBtn1, QuitBtn2, QuitBtn3, QuitBtn4) on the main window.  The last QPushButton created, QuitBtn4, is the only QPushButton that will process the mouse clicked event.  The other three QPushButtons do not respond to their mouse clicked event.

What do I need to do to have all the QPushButtons respond to their mouse clicked events?

My code is below.

The final application will have a background image with the push buttons place on top of it.  The buttons’ positions will not allow me to use the QLayout Widgets.  I am using absolute positioning using setGeometry().

I am not using QT Creator or QT Designer.

Thank You.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#inclued <QString>

class MyButton : public QWidget
{

public:
     MyButton(QString str, int x, int y, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
};

MyButton::MyButton(QString str, int x, int y, QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    auto *myBtn = new QPushButton(str,this);
    myBtn->setGeometry(x ,y, 75, 30);

    connect(myBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, qApp, &QApplication::quit);
}

Int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget widow;

    MyButton QuitBtn1(“Quit1”, 20, 20, &window);

    MyButton QuitBtn2(“Quit2”, 100, 20, &window);

    MyButton QuitBtn3(“Quit3”, 20, 80, &window);

    MyButton QuitBtn4(“Quit4”, 100, 80, &window);

    window.resize(250, 150);
    window.setWindowTitle(“QPushButton”);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the *real* code: `Class MyButton : public QWidget` can't possibly compile.  Nor can `#inclued <QString>` .

Comment: The code compiles and runs on RHEL 8.  I am using Qt5.

Comment: It can't compile - Int -> int, Class -> class ...

Comment: Can you be more specific in your comment.  I just check it against my source code.  The source code compiles.  I do not understand what you mean by "It can't compile - Int -> int, Class -> class ...".  I found the Class -> class error.  I donot see the Int -> int error.

Comment: @FrankHaymes `c++` is case sensitive: `Class` and `class` are *not* the same thing.  Similarly for `Int` and `int`.

Comment: Why are you inheriting `MyButton` from `QWidget` and not from `QPushButton` directly? Then it should work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you derive MyButton from QWidget, it doesn't make MyButton a proper widget. For this, MyButton should be declared in a header file which is passed into moc for the necessary details like meta-information etc. Then also MyButton requires a Q_OBJECT declaration.
The easiest workaround here would be changing the following line:

```
auto *myBtn = new QPushButton(str,parent);
```

By passing `parent` instead of `this` you get the correct wiring of the QObjects hidden in QApplication and the push buttons.

As implied above, you can leave out the QWidget part and make MyButton a simple C++-class.

Comment: Thanks,  The change worked.  When I include the Q_OBJECT declaration I get a make error "undefined reference to 'vtable for Mybutton'.  It work without the Q_OBJECT declaration.

Comment: To get a true QWidget derived class, you need to put MyButton in a header, call moc and add Q_OBJECT. That's the way Qt works

Comment: Thanks,  I will look at making the MyButton in to a QWidget derived class.